# How to populate a mapping table with complex mapping structure

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables: `Device` And `DeviceStatus`

`DeviceStatus` has these 5 rows:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NEW |
| 2 | First Check Passed |
| 3 | Third Check Passed |
| 4 | Packed |
| 5 | Second Check Passed |

Previously `Device` had only one `DeviceStatus` and it always changed in order 1 -> 2 -> 5 -> 3 -> 4

Now device can have many statuses, so I created a mapping table `DeviceDeviceStatuses` and I need to populate it, including for every `Device` its current status and every status that it had passed.

For example, if `Device` with Id 42 had status 3, the `DeviceDeviceStatuses` has to be populated with

| DeviceId | DeviceStatusId |
| --- | --- |
| 42 | 1 |
| 42 | 2 |
| 42 | 5 |
| 42 | 3 |

What query should I write to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do it by myself. Here's the query:

```
INSERT INTO "DeviceDeviceStatus"("DeviceStatusesId", "DeviceTechNumber")
    SELECT
            "Devices"."Id",
            unnest(
                (array[1, 2, 5, 3, 4])
                    [:array_position(array[1, 2, 5, 3, 4], "DeviceStatus"."Id")])
        FROM "Devices" 
            JOIN "DeviceStatus" ON "Devices"."DeviceStatusId" = "DeviceStatus"."Id"
```